# Invalid data. Nested arrays are not supported Firestore java

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As firestore does not support Nested arrays, I changed the model and stored the nested arrays in another class but I am still facing the same error.
**Here is the model**

```
public class Assignmentsdata implements Serializable {

String assignmentId;
String teacherId;
int game_nameId;
String sectionId;
String levelId;
String startTime;
String endTime;
String groupName;

// Another class that has nested arrays.
Progress progress;

int number_of_exercises;
int exStatus;
public Assignmentsdata() {

}
// getters and setters here.
}
```

**Here is the class that have nested arrays**

```
public class Progress {


public Progress() {
}

ArrayList<String> progressList;

public Progress(ArrayList<String> progressList) {
    this.progressList = progressList;
}

public ArrayList<String> getProgressList() {
    return progressList;
}

public void setProgressList(ArrayList<String> progressList) {
    this.progressList = progressList;
}
}
```

*I am trying to save the Array of AssignmentData in firestore.*

```
db.collection("users").document(docName).update(
                        "myArchiveList", FieldValue.arrayUnion(assignmentsdata)).
                addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task){}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I found the answer, after spending my entire day on the problem. Actually, if your object is alright then if you still face the same error then this error is misleading. Actually instead of pushing all elements at once using
> `FieldValue.arrayUnion`, you have to push one element at a time not the entire list. Just use the loop through the items.